# When are homeomorphic $G$-spaces isomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, equivariant-topology

Let $X,Y$ be $G$-spaces ($G$ a topological group). In general $X$ and $Y$ can be homeomorphic as topological spaces without being isomorphic as $G$-spaces.

For example $X=Y=S^1$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$ acting on $X$ by rotating by $\pi$ and on $Y$ by reflecting along $x$-axis. Then $X$ and $Y$ are clearly homeomorphic but not isomorphic as $G$-spaces, since the action on $X$ has no fixed points and the action on $Y$ has two fixed points $-1$ and $1$.

What are sufficient conditions for $G$-spaces $X,Y$ so that homeomorphic $\iff$ isomorphic as $G$-spaces?

For example, clearly, if $X,Y$ are trivial $G$-spaces this equivalence holds.

Comment: This condition is equivalent to asking a question: what topological spaces allow only trivial action of $G$ on them? Such situation is obviously extremely rare. One such case is when $G$ is connected, while $X$ totally disconnected.

Comment: @freakish is it true that for example for a $2$-sphere all actions of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are isomorphic to an orthogonal action, so that one could say that if the fixed point sets are in some sense equal, like equal "dimension", then homeomorphic is the same as isomorphic? Is there a wider class of such examples, if this one is true?

Comment: This question seems way to broad for any kind of answer other than a laundry list of examples. Your comment just above is more focussed, and your question could be improved by gaining focus in some such manner.

Comment: @psl2Z consider $\mathbb{Z}_4$ acting on $S^1$ via rotations by $90^\circ$. And second action of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ on $S^1$ via rotations by $180^\circ$. These $\mathbb{Z}_4$-spaces are not $\mathbb{Z}_4$-isomorphic, even though both have no fixed points. They are not isomorphic because orbits are of different order.

Comment: In fact, it is not hard to construct an example of two actions of $G$ on $X$ such that all orbits are homeomorphic but these are not $G$-isomorphic actions. Consider two homeomorphic but not isomorphic groups $G$, $H$, and consider obvious actions of $G\times H$ on $G$ and on $H$. These actions are not $G$-isomorphic, because it is a general fact that isomorphic orbits imply conjugate stabilizers, which cannot happen here.